# Where to disable BrowserSync? path? files? console? Angular 2

Tags: angular, synchronization

I use Angular 2. I would like to disable/delete Browser sync. But can not find out how to do it, or via cmd or code? Which path?
Need help)

Version angular 2.0.0-rc.1"

```
"Projest structure:
-Build/
-NodeModules/
-SRC/
-Typings/
-gunlpfile.ts
-bsconfig.json
-tsconfig.json
-tslint.json
-typings.json"
```

this is gulpfile.ts:

```
"use strict";

const gulp = require("gulp");
const del = require("del");
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const tsc = require("gulp-typescript");
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const tsProject = tsc.createProject("tsconfig.json");
const tslint = require('gulp-tslint');


gulp.task('clean', (cb) => {
return del(["build"], cb);
});
```

continue

```
gulp.task('tslint', () => {
return gulp.src("src/**/*.ts")
    .pipe(tslint())
    .pipe(tslint.report('prose'));
});


gulp.task("compile", ["tslint"], () => {
let tsResult = gulp.src("src/**/*.ts")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(tsc(tsProject))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});


gulp.task("sass", () => {
 return gulp.src("src/**/*.{sass,scss}")
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
.pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
.pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
.pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});


 gulp.task("resources", () => {
 return gulp.src(["src/**/*", "!**/*.{sass,scss,ts}"])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```

this is part of gulpfile.ts

Comment: just remove the code for browserSync simply ? are you using angular2 CLI ?

Comment: Can you add more information? Where are you using it? Versions, project structure... [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am new in it. what means CLI?
wheee to remove this code. tell the truth I searched every gulp file but coudn't fine any BrowserSync variable

Comment: Use the [codeSync](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-codeSync) option in the *bsconfig.json* file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Angular2-Seed project then take a look into `seed.config.ts`

```
 /**
       * Configurations for NPM module configurations. Add to or override in project.config.ts.
       * If you like, use the mergeObject() method to assist with this.
       */
      PLUGIN_CONFIGS: any = {
        /**
         * The BrowserSync configuration of the application.
         * The default open behavior is to open the browser. To prevent the browser from opening use the `--b`  flag when
         * running `npm start` (tested with serve.dev).
         * Example: `npm start -- --b`
         * @type {any}
         */
        'browser-sync': {
          middleware: [require('connect-history-api-fallback')({ index: `${this.APP_BASE}index.html` })],
          port: this.PORT,
          startPath: this.APP_BASE,
          open: argv['b'] ? false : true,
          injectChanges: false,
          server: {
            baseDir: `${this.DIST_DIR}/empty/`,
            routes: {
              [`${this.APP_BASE}${this.APP_DEST}`]: this.APP_DEST,
              [`${this.APP_BASE}node_modules`]: 'node_modules',
              [`${this.APP_BASE.replace(/\/$/, '')}`]: this.APP_DEST
            }
          }
        }
      };
```

Comment: can't fin it. I don't think I use it. i wrote version